# Login System not working! Can't confirm login information

Tags: python

Basically what I'm trying to do is confirm if the register = login information inside the file.txt. I can't find the mistake I did, so if someone could help, that'd be amazing!

```
def login():
   user_login = input ("Type your username: ")
   user_password = input ("Type your password: ")

   for name in user_login:
        a,b = name.split(",")
        if (a==user_register and b==user_password):
            print ("Login succesfull")
        else:
            print ("Login failed")

           




    
def register():
    global user_register
    global user_password
    user_register = input ("Type username: ")
    user_password = input ("Type password: ")

    file = open("file.txt", "a")
    file.write(user_register+","+user_password+"\n")
    file.close()

    print("Registered")

login()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not very tidy, I don't think there is a need to define global variables for such a simple operation.

Try an OOP structure like this:

```
import os

class UsersManager:
    def __init__(self, users_file: str):
        self.users = users_file

        if not os.path.exists(users_file):
            with open(users_file, 'a') as file:
                file.close()

    def user_exists(self, username: str, password: str) -> bool:
        with open(self.users, 'r') as file:
            for line in file.readlines():
                data = line.replace('\n', '').split(',')
                if data[0] == username and data[1] == password:
                    return True

        return False

    def login(self, username: str, password: str) -> bool:
        if self.user_exists(username, password):
            return True

        return False

    def register(self, username: str, password: str) -> bool:
        if self.user_exists(username, password):
            return False

        with open(self.users, 'a') as file:
            file.write(f'{username},{password}\n')
            return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    user = 'Mark'
    pwd = 'Markspassword'

    manager = UsersManager('users.txt')

    if manager.user_exists(user, pwd):
        manager.login(user, pwd)
        print('Login complete!')

    else:
        print('Adding a new user...')
        manager.register(user, pwd)
        print(f'New user ({user}) registred with password: {pwd}')
```